# Sinatra threadpool for multiple slow IO calls

Tags: ruby, sinatra, threadpool

I have an application that makes several slow http calls on certain inbound API requests and I'd like those to run in *parallel* because there are several and they are slow.

For a thread pool, I've previously used http://burgestrand.se/articles/quick-and-simple-ruby-thread-pool.html.

Are there any architecturally sound solutions for running this in *parallel*, with or without a thread pool?

**Edit**
My apologies, I was watching a movie while typing this up and wrote "serial" in the places where I have italicized "parallel". Thanks to @Catnapper for the catch. How embarassing

Comment: I'm having trouble making sense of this.  Are you sure you mean serial and not parallel?

Comment: @Catnapper How embarrassing, was not paying attention at all when I wrote that. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Do these slow http calls generate responses that need further processing by your app, or are they fire-and-forget?

Comment: @Catnapper there is some, minimal processing within the app before it returns a value to the end client that is calculated from the the different http calls

Comment: Threads would work fine if the processing of each http call is truly fast.  Whether or not a thread pool is advantageous depends on how many threads you're trying to spawn.  If the threads bottleneck on processing, and you are using MRI, I think you will want each thread to fork a child process and use some IPC mechanism to relay the results to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For good leads try Sidekiq:

http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/

And Celluloid:

http://www.unlimitednovelty.com/2011/05/introducing-celluloid-concurrent-object.html

Comment: great reading, thanks! I'll update in the AM when I've had a chance to try

Comment: Sidekiq is a great lead and I think would do the trick. I ended up changing the architecture of the app around and separating off a service layer that was built for node.js.